# How to test jpa connection?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm creating an application with JPA and Swing, it works fine, but now I want to test if JPA has connection with my database, for example, if I add a wrong IP in JDBC_URL does not connect in database and I want to know how to get the exception when it happen. There's any way to do this ?

Comment: You could at least try a simple query which should fail if the connection can't be established. This also could be used to periodically check whether the DB is still reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test it..

```
public class JdbcTest {

    private final static String URL = "jdbc:oracle:...";
    private final static String USER = "sa";
    private final static String PASSWORd = "";

    public static TestConnection() {
        Connection c = null;  
        try {    
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");    
            System.out.println("Driver found");    
            System.out.println("Connecting..."); 
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);    
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            System.out.println(Cannot connect the database);   
        } finally {    
            if (c != null) {       
                c.close();        
            }    
        }    
    }            
}
```